# Boostrap Nav bar: how do I make each tab highlight as "active" when I tab across?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a nav bar from twitter Boostrap.

[image: Boostrap Nav]

Great - my question is, how do I get the subsequent tabs to highlight red with the previous tab going grey, as I tab across ?

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Job Analysis</a></li>
    <li role="presentation">{{link_to('crews', 'Crews')}}</li>
    <li role="presentation">{{link_to('contractors', 'Contractors')}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the css as given by Bootstrap for the active class:

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is the css for an inactive tab:

```
.nav-tabs>li>a {
    margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) from the bootstrap doc.

Answer (score 2):

You could add your own code to change the active class for the current tab.
In this case it would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
        $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Check this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/8DULSi0lNV

Comment: Brilliant - thank you .. one problem, the script moves the class to the next tab, but then a moment later it goes back to "Job Analysis"

Sorry, I'm not good with js.   I placed the script at the bottom of the page between a couple of script tags. 

I would prefer it in it's own file. I expect that I have messed up the "on load" or is this Jquery  and need "document ready" ?  

So what am I doing wrong ?   

Many thanks !

Comment: Check the edited answer, you just need to include those lines in your js script at the bottom of the page, if you have any doubts feel free to include your complete js code.

Comment: Hi Patrick - I have been struggling for the past hour to make things work.  The problem is that the js works, but it only works for about .5 of a second and then the original css is applied. so in other words, the tab changes for about .5 sec and then goes back. 

Any ideas ?? 

MANY Thanks !

Comment: @Vince try to test this http://www.bootply.com/sEBEdfjavc: $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav a").on("click", function(e){   e.preventDefault();
        $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
});

Comment: @pstrick-lc 

HI thanks Patrick ! Well it kind of worked .. but then again is does not work. You see my tabed pages are inside the Boostrap Dashboard page as given http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#

So your new code does now indeed move the highlighted tabs across the page, however it also somehow has disabled the links down the LHS of the page.

Comment: Hi Vince, i think i don't understand which links are now disabled, could you reproduce the issue using bootply? I generated this one with the dashboard example: http://www.bootply.com/BrIzl9y8U3

Comment: Hi Patrick - Umm .. I'll give it a try ... I'm placing this js inside a Laravel 4, 3 layered template made up of the Bootstrap dashboard. cheers !

Comment: Hi Patrick - I've been an absolute idiot. When I first installed the Bootstrap tabs I did not notice that in an totally different part of the BS user pages / manual is a presentation on how to use JS with BS. So ... I put you to some work for no benefit. 

Now comes the really big shameful admission, I can not for the life of me get the BS JS to work either !  :o( 

I'm terrible with JS .. I do not dare ask you to put any more thoughts into this - cheers and thanks !  !